# Java Socket BufferedReader Null

Tags: java, sockets, null, bufferedreader

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String hostName = "127.0.0.1";
    int portNumber = 4848;
    Socket echoSocket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String userInput;
    while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
        out.println(userInput);
        System.out.println("echo: " + in.readLine());
    }
}
```

It is supposed to echo back what you write by sending it to the socket and getting it from the socket again. What happens is that when i enter something in and press enter it takes around 10 seconds then is says `echo: null`.

## Expected

#### Input

> Test

#### Output

> echo: Test

## Reality

#### Input

> Test

#### Output

> echo: null

My question is:

- What rookie mistake am I doing?
- How do I fix it?

  ## READ BEFORE COMMENTING

  I need to test the functionality of a socket. By doing something simple like this, it helps me to understand how to use them. I want to create a live chat server. However, i cannot if this simple program does not work. I am not stupid enough not to use userInput. I know.

Comment: You want to echo userInput not input.readLine

Comment: @zack6849 the purpose is to test the usage of the socket to send and retrieve data.

Comment: It is exactly as @zack6849 said. You want to echo `userInput`. You've already read it. Echo it. You're throwing it away. Don't throw it away. Echo it. The line you just read. Not another line.

Comment: @EJP I need to test the functionality of a socket. By doing something simple like this, it helps me to understand how to use them. I want to create a live chat server. However, i cannot if this simple program does not work.

Comment: And you will never get it to work if you keep ignoring what you're being told here, and merely restating the obvious instead.

Comment: ill figure it out myself instead

Comment: Instead of what? You've been given the solution.Twice. If you're going to completely ignore everything you're told here, why are you posting? NB The final sentences of your question are inconsistent with the evidence.

Comment: I don't know what the others are about, but, what makes you think that the echoing server works correctly? What is this server? What is its protocol? How do you test it?

Comment: @kumesena That makes two of you, but there is a glaring bug in this code that has been stated twice. There is no need to hypotheses a further bug elsewhere.

Comment: @kumesana i am testing if the echoing server works, that is the question

Comment: If you're trying to test a server, don't expect it to respect the expected protocol. Read its input on another thread than the one you write to it, and read the InputStream as-is, unbuffered, unwrapped to a reader.

Comment: @kumesana You are barking up the wrong tree. Read the first comment above. Don't add to the confusion. We have enough. But in any case none of your suggestions make any sense.

Comment: @EJP the first comment is advising to ignore that there is an echo server at play. It is a stupid advice.

Comment: @kumesana thank you, i will try to figure it out now

Comment: @kumesana It is already clear from the output provided that the server is operating, receiving input, responding, closing the connection properly, and that it understands and sends lines, and that is the full extent of the protocol required to debug it. There is in fact no evidence here whatsoever that it isn't working perfectly. Any stupidity here is not being contributed by me. The only problem here is that the OP is ignoring the solution provided.

Comment: @EJP I don't know what you believe, but you referenced the first comment, and you agreed that the variable to output as echo is userInput. userInput is read from the console input, not from a server. It clearly doesn't comply with the intent.

Comment: @kumesana exactly. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was accessing the `InputStream` and `OutputStream` of the `echoSocket` on the same `Thread`.